# Stata: need help creating a binary variable from panel data

Tags: for-loop, stata

I have a dataset in which a household id (`hhid`) and a member id (`mid`) identify a unique person. I have results from two separate surveys taken a year apart (`surveyYear`). I also have data on whether or not the individual was enrolled in school at the time.

I want a binary variable which signifies if the individual in question dropped out of school between the surveys (i.e. 1 if dropped and 0 if still in school)

I have a decent understanding of Stata but this coding challenge seems a little beyond me because I am not sure how to compare the in-school status of the later `id` with the earlier `id` and then propagate that result into a binary column.

Here is an example of what I need

Previously:

```
     +----------------------------------+
     | hhid   mid   survey~r   inschool |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |    1     2          3          1 |
  2. |    1     2          4          1 |
  3. |    1     3          3          1 |
  4. |    1     3          4          1 |
  5. |    2     1          3          1 |
  6. |    2     1          4          0 |
  7. |    2     2          3          0 |
  8. |    2     2          4          0 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

After:

```
     +--------------------------------------------+
     | hhid   mid   survey~r   inschool   dropped |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1     2          3          1         0 |
  2. |    1     2          4          1         0 |
  3. |    1     3          3          1         0 |
  4. |    1     3          4          1         0 |
  5. |    2     1          3          1         1 |
  6. |    2     1          4          0         1 |
  7. |    2     2          3          0         0 |
  8. |    2     2          4          0         0 |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The name "STATA" was used briefly by the company around 1985, but not since. Whichever source you took it from was not well informed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bysort hhid mid (surveyyear) : gen dropped = inschool[1] == 1 & inschool[2] == 0
```

The commentary is longer than the code:

1. Within blocks of observations with the same `hhid` and `mid`, sort by `surveyyear`.
2. You want students who were `inschool` in year 3 but not in year 4. So, `inschool` is 1 in the first observation and 0 in the second.
3. Here subscripting `[1]` and `[2]` refers to order within blocks of observations defined by the `by:` statement.

If further detail is needed see e.g. [this article](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004). Note that contrary to one tag, no loop is needed (or, if you wish, that the loop over possibilities is built in to the `by:` framework).